# Not able to customitze AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

I get the exception `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied` but I would like to have my own custom exception.

This is what I have tried:

```java
package com.example.dq.exception;

@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({IllegalArgumentException.class, PSQLException.class, ExpiredJwtException.class, MalformedJwtException.class, SignatureException.class, AccessDeniedException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptions(Exception exception) {
        HttpStatus status;
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Caught exception of type: " + exception.getClass().getName());

        switch (exception.getClass().getName()) {
            case "org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
                errorList.add("Access Denied");
            }
            case "io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
                errorList.add("Invalid Token");
            }
            case "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                errorList.add(exception.getMessage());
            }
            case "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                errorList.add(exception.getMessage());
            }
            case "io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
                errorList.add("Token has expired.");
            }
            case "io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException" -> {
                status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
                errorList.add("Malformed token.");
            }
            default -> {
                status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                errorList.add("An unexpected error occurred.");
                System.out.println("Unhandled exception of type: " + exception.getClass().getName());
            }
        }

        Response response = Response.builder()
                .code(status.name())
                .status(status)
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .messages(errorList)
                .build();

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(response);
    }
}
```

This works for all exceptions but not for `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException`. In case I receive this exception, `handleExceptions()` will not even be invoked.

Since that didn't work, I tried it through a different way, which is:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    http.sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy()));

    // Authorization
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
            auth
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/oauth", "/api/user-profile/**").authenticated()
                    .requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/**", "/logout").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    );

    http.httpBasic(withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling(e -> e.accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())); // <--

    http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}
```

```java
public class CustomAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Yayyy, I've been found!");
    }
}
```

However, both of them do not work. My code is getting ignored.

Comment: @RomanC what exactly do you not understand when I mention that my code is getting ignored? This is the problem. Please read again!

Comment: I'd set an exception breakpoint on `AccessDeniedException` to see where it is thrown, and which exception handlers are on the stack at this point in time. That said, I think you're on the right track telling Spring Security about handling that exception rather than using an RestControllerAdvice, because the rest controller (and therefore it's advice) shouldn't be invoked if Spring Security denies access to that URL.

Comment: @xRay What do I read? You didn't explain your problem. Your question is a mistery of `AccedsDeniedException` which you can't handle? What did you try? *Read this*: Checked exception thrown when a file system operation is denied, typically due to a file permission or other access check.
This exception is not related to the `AccessControlException` or `SecurityException` thrown by access controllers or security managers when access to a file is denied.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `AccessDeniedException` is not a subclass of `Exception`, and therefore, your `@ExceptionHandler` for Exception won't catch it directly. Spring Security's `AccessDeniedException` is a specialization of `RuntimeException`.

To handle `AccessDeniedException`, you need to specifically include it in the `@ExceptionHandler`. You can do this by adding a separate method for handling `AccessDeniedException`

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({IllegalArgumentException.class, PSQLException.class, ExpiredJwtException.class, MalformedJwtException.class, SignatureException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleOtherExceptions(Exception exception) {
        // Your existing logic for handling other exceptions
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException exception) {
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
        List<String> errorList = Collections.singletonList("Access Denied");

        Response response = Response.builder()
                .code(status.name())
                .status(status)
                .timestamp(LocalDateTime.now())
                .messages(errorList)
                .build();

        return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried the same but when I debug, I see that the method `handleAccessDeniedException()` is not getting invoked.

Comment: In that case, I think the exception is not thrown from your controller.  So actually you need to catch it from filterchain. `http.exceptionHandling( accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler())`  
Also you can try removing other filter so that you can check these are not overriding the issue
`http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
    http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`